# How do you change the core forum module to only show a certain depth?

Tags: 8

I am using the core forum module. If I have this forum structure:

```
- A1
 - A2
  - A3
- B1
 - B2
  - B3
- C1
 - C2
  -C3
```

I want it to show A1, B1 and C1. As well as A2 and B2. But not A3, B3 and C3.

I checked the forum-list.html.twig file, but before I start hacking away, I was wondering if there isn't a more obvious hook of some sort I could use to do this?

Comment: If you want to change list of forums using hook try `hook_preprocess_HOOK` like `function MYMODULE_preprocess_forum_list(&$variables) {
// dump here forums and search for the forum you want to remove and unset it
  dpm($variables['forums']);
}`

Comment: Shut the front door. That's easy! Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped, i will post it as an answer if someone needs in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change list of forums using hook try `hook_preprocess_HOOK` something like like

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_forum_list(&$variables) { 
// dump here forums and search for the forum you want to remove and unset it . 
 dpm($variables['forums']); 
}
```

Comment: There's a follow up question if you want to take a stab at it --> https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/287705/how-to-show-forums-even-if-you-dont-have-access